# How to copy new files from SFTP using WinSCP script

Tags: sftp, winscp

I want to download only new files from one SFTP server using WinSCP.

Suppose, I have 10 files in source and destination today.
Tomorrow one new file may be added to the source. In this scenario, I want to copy the new file only into destination.

I am using below script:

```
open sftp_connection
cd /path
option transfer binary
get "*.txt" localpath
close
exit
```

By using above, I am able to copy all files, but I want only new files which are not available in destination.

Thanks,
Srikrishna.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add [`-neweronly` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get#neweronly) to your [`get` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get):

```
get -neweronly *.txt C:\local\path\*
```

For a very similar results, you can also use [`synchronize` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_synchronize):

```
synchronize local . C:\local\path -filemask=*.txt
```

See also WinSCP article on [Downloading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_download_most_recent_file).